# Using highcharts-more with highcharts version 5

Tags: highcharts

I am using version 5 of highcharts and unfortunately upgrading to version 8 is not an option. I also using highcharts-more and highcharts-3d, both deprecated at the moment. My question is, even using version 5 can I remove "more" and "3d" from my dependencies and reference the ones on highcharts folder?

Comment: What do you have in mind by saying that highcharts-more and 3d modules are deprecated? And what do you have in mind that you want to remove it from your dependencies? Have you installed your Highcharts v 5.0 via npm? If yes - the highcharts-more module and others should be included in it.

Comment: Hi Sebastian. The way the application was set is that they installed all three packages via npm, separately. That is why I want to remove highcharts-more and highcharts-3d from the dev-dependencies and use the one included in highcharts.
I was afraid that removing them will get me some issues.

Comment: Interesting - official Highcharts npm offers only whole highcharts package to get - not separated